# Ubuntu 13..04 reinstall Unity and gnome3

Tags: ubuntu

I remove unity and gnome 3 in my Ubuntu. I am using now just mate desktop. But I would like to restore Unity and Gnome3.

So I tried [this re-install solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313126/reinstall-unity-on-13-04-from-cinnamon), but now i get:

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libunity-core-6.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libnux-4.0-dev (>= 4.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libunity-dev (>= 4.0.0~) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libdee-dev but it is not going to be installed
 nautilus : Depends: nautilus-data (< 1:3.7) but 1:3.8.2-0ubuntu1~ubuntu13.04.1 is to be installed
 nautilus-sendto-empathy : Depends: empathy (= 3.6.4-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What can I do to resolve this?

EDIT: I already tried apt-get install -f but there is no list to repeare

Comment: I try also with sudo aptitude install libglib2.0-dev

Answer (score 0):

if you have problem for package installation use `apt-get install -f` , `APT system` itself repair your problem. of course if you have lack of package dependency or half installed.

Comment: I already tried apt-get install -f but there is no list to repeare.

Comment: So problem is not you and your machine, probelem from server side.Of course if you  fill `/etc/apt/sources.list` correctly